# How to filter a List with two object of different class and with compare field in Java

Tags: java, spring, stream, java-stream, apache-commons

I have two different list. I want to find and filter by field not on the other list. For example.

```
List<ObjectOne>      List<ObjectTwo>
field | value        field | value
{id=5, name="aaa"}   {xId=4, text="aaa"}
{id=6, name="bbb"}   {xId=6, text="bbb"}
{id=7, name="ccc"}   {xId=5, text="ccc"}
```

If I want to filter one list, I am using **org.springframework.cglib.core.CollectionUtils** like that

```
CollectionUtils.filter(objectOne, s -> (
(ObjectOne) s).getId() == anyObject.getXId()
&&  (ObjectOne) s).getName() == anyObject.getText());
```

But I want to compare two List, and I want to find noncontains value like that

```
objectOne = {id=5, name="aaa"} , {id=7, name="ccc"}
```

How am I filter with streamApi or any third-party libraries ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`noneMatch` helps you here.

```
objectOnes.stream()
          .filter(x -> objectTwos.stream()
                                 .noneMatch(y -> y.text.equals(x.name) && y.xId == x.id))
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a list of `ObjectOne` from the list of `ObjectTwo` as this:

```
List<ObjectOne> objectOne = listTwo.stream()
        .map(x -> new ObjectOne(x.getxId(), x.getText()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

And then you can use `retainAll` to find the common elements:

```
listOne.retainAll(objectOne);
```

---

if you wont modify the list of `ObjectOne`, then you can create a second list from `listOne`

```
List<ObjectOne> listOne2 = new ArrayList<>(listOne);
listOne2.retainAll(objectOne);
```

Note, this solution need to use `hashcode` and `equals` in `ObjectOne`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do this with just one stream, but at least I got a solution for two.

```
List<ObjectOne> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
List<ObjectTwo> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
list1.stream()
        .filter(o1 -> isInObjectTwoList(list2, o1))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

private boolean isInObjectTwoList(List<ObjectTwo> objectTwoList, ObjectOne o1) {
    return objectTwoList.stream()
            .filter(o2 -> o2.getText().equals(o1.getValue()))
            .findAny()
            .isPresent();
}
```